# how to remove subscribe when a client disconnect?

Tags: autobahn

```
class MyServerProtocol(WampServerProtocol):

    @exportRpc
    def getSubscribers(self):
        print "call getSubscribers"

        subscriptions = []
        for key, value in enumerate(self.factory.subscriptions):
            subscriptions.append(value)
        return json.dumps(subscriptions)

    def onSessionOpen(self):
        print "someone has logined"

        self.registerForPubSub("http://example.com/event/", True)

        self.registerMethodForRpc("http://example.com/event/getSubscribers",
            self,
            MyServerProtocol.getSubscribers)


    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "someone disconnect", reason

        self.factory._unsubscribeClient(self)
        self.factory._removeSession(self)

        WampProtocol.connectionLost(self, reason)
        WebSocketServerProtocol.connectionLost(self, reason)
```

————————————————————————————

```
ab.connect(chat.wsuri,
        function (session) {
            sess = session;

            sess.prefix("event", chat.prefix);
            sess.subscribe("event:" + chat.channel, chat.subscribeSuccess); //public topic, subscribe a common topic
            sess.subscribe("event:" + chat.username, chat.subscribeSuccess);//privite topic, subscribe myself topic

            chat.stateUpdate(true);

        },

        function (code, reason) {
            sess = null;
            alert(reason);
            chat.stateUpdate(false);
        }
)
```

## if chat to everyone, publish to public topic

## if chat to specified client, publish to privite topic

————————————————————————————

Q1: I need a function that when a client disconnect server, update subscribers.
I add connectionLost method, but it does not work.
I print the param "reason", I find that this function remove public and privite topic at the same time.
But I just need to remove privite topic, am i right? but, how to do this?
————————————————————————————

Q2: how to broadcasting a message to told everyone, clientX has left or clientY has logined?
I don't know how to implement this function.

Answer (score 0):

**Q.1**  Here the idea is to make an array, which contains all connected clients.
How? simply make register/unregister functions, when each user connects, add entry in array, when disconnects remove entry from array. Now to inform users, In register function, before adding this user, call broadcast function (explained below) and in unregister function after removing the loggedout user from this array, call broadcast function.

**Q.2 (Broadcast Function):** This is fairly simple. Since websockets are unicast bidirectional, so for broadcasting, make a function where you loop through your array (as explained above), and send message to each client in this loop.